# Android signing, can't export upload certificate of key generated in Android Studio, "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: android, android-studio, certificate, keytool, android-keystore

I need to send my PEM upload certificate to google because I lost my key.

This is what they tell me:

> Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:
>
> `keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks`
>
> Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:
>
> `keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks`

In Android Studio I generate the new key and the app compiles and is able to generate a signed build, but when i try to export the certificate it says:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

The password is correct I tried many times and its always the same.

When generating the key via command line I can export the certificate, but I cannot use the key to sing the app in android studio, the error is the same.